# node js undefined mongodb connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have 3 files

**./custom/db.js** For Database Connection to mongodb

```
const mongodb= require('mongodb');
var mongoclient= require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var dburl1= 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
var _db;

    function dbconn(){
      var _db;
      async function books(){

        await mongoclient.connect(dburl1, {keepAlive: 30000, connectTimeoutMS: 30000, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db)=>{
          dbo=  db.db('books');
          _db= dbo; 
         
        })
        return _db;
      }
      return {
        books: books, 
      }
    }
module.exports= dbconn();
```

**./custom/ctrg.js**  To get data from mongodb

```
async function books_by_ctrg(ctrg, limit, start) {
        console.log(ctrg);
    if(start == null) start=0;

        const dbo = await  db.books();

        // console.log(dbo);
        await dbo.collection('books1').find({}).skip(start).limit(limit).toArray((err, result)=>{if(err){console.log(err); return err;}else{data= result;}})
    
        return data;
};
```

**./router/home.js** Router file (using Express with EJS)

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res) {
    var data =await books_data.get_book_ctrg('Latest_Books', 7, 0);
    var headerdata= {
            title: "", 
            des: "", 
            keywords: ""
            
    };
    // console.log(data);
    res.render('home.ejs', {data: data, headerdata: headerdata});
})
```

These All Above There File to get Data From DB for Home Page

**ISSUE**

**On First Load** i got this err

```
node:6536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
    at Object.books_by_ctrg [as get_book_ctrg] (C:\node\custom\ctrg.js:15:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async C:\node\routes\home.js:12:15
(node:6536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6536) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**On Second Load**  (it means database connection is now working "No File Change Just Refresh in Browser" )

```
TypeError: C:\node\views\home.ejs:67
    65|         <div class="course-slider owl-carousel">
    66|
 >> 67|     <% data.forEach(book=>{ %>
    68|         <a href="<%= book.link %>">
    69|             <div class="course-item">
    70|                 <figure class="course-preview">

Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:14:13)
    at home (C:\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\node\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (C:\node\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\node\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\node\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\node\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\node\routes\home.js:20:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

**after Those two visit or Refresh** (Everything goes fine no error no warning everything just perfect)

Comment: nodejs : v12.16.3, MongoDb: v5.x.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error already tells you a lot.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined.

This means when you call `await dbo.collection('books1')` the `dbo` variable is `undefined`. That tells us that `db.books();` doesn't return the [`Db`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Db.html) instance that you need. So the problem lies in the `./custom/db.js` file.

In that file there are a couple of issues.

```
var _db; // <-- 1st definition of _db (it's not wrong, but just confusing).

function dbconn(){
  var _db; // <-- 2nd definition of _db (this should be the only definition).
  async function books(){

    // Because you use a callback, no promise is returned, therefor it will not await.
    // @see http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/MongoClient.html#.connect
    await mongoclient.connect(dburl1, {keepAlive: 30000, connectTimeoutMS: 30000, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db)=>{
      dbo=  db.db('books'); // <-- dbo is never defined
      _db= dbo; //
    })

    // _db will still be undefined because await didn't work.
    // This will cause the error.
    return _db;
  }
  
  return {
    books: books, 
  }
}
```

### Why is `undefined` returned?

So the main culprit is that because of the [`callback` parameter on `mongoclient.connect`, that function will not return a Promise](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/MongoClient.html#.connect). Therefor the `await` keyword will have nothing to await and will continue straight to the `return` keyword, returning an `undefined` value.

### Why does it work the second time?

`var _db` is defined at the top of function. This is the variable where the results of `db.db('books')` will be stored in. This variable will be inside of a closure, meaning that after return `return { books: books }` it will still exist inside of the scope of the function.

Now the first time, `_db` is undefined and returned immediately. But meanwhile, `mongoclient.connect()` will start running and update the `_db` variable in the closure. So if you wait long enough for `connect` function to finish, the `_db` variable will now be updated and have a `Db` instance. The same thing will happen for the second, third and every other time, but the difference then is that `_db` has already been updated and will not be `undefined` anymore.

### Modifying your code.

I've looked at some examples and notices that they create an instance of [`MongoClient`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/MongoClient.html) with the url to DB and the settings for the connection.

See the example below. It first creates an instance and then uses that instance to connect and to return the `Db` that you need.

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const dburl1 = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

function dbconn() {
  const mongoclient = new MongoClient(dburl1, {
    connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  });

  async function books() {
    try {
      await mongoclient.connect();
      return mongoclient.db("books");
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      await client.close();
    }
  }

  return {
    books
  };
}

module.exports = dbconn();
```

Comment: Maybe That's Not Issue The Same Script Run Fine When i refresh The Page . The Dbo undefined returned of first page load not in second time

Comment: Well, the first time `_db` will be undefined, but it seems that `mongoclient.connect` will still update the global `_db` variable after it has been returned. That means that the second time `_db` is returned it will no longer be undefined and have a `Db` instance. This answer will solve that issue.

Comment: Could You Explain me Little Bit Why It does Work fine on second load or refresh.  Thanks Alot for Pointing me out About the same i have fixed my ctrg.js file do now everything just great.